# Logging request and response json payloads with Hystrix Feign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hystrix, netflix-feign

I am using Hystrix Feign with Spring Encoder.
I want to log exact request (Json) payload that goes out with each request
and also the response.
How can I do that?

Comment: What's your Logger.level configuration?

Comment: It's info on production. But even in debug level, we get toString representation in the logs not the actual request payloads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define your feign configuration, you have to [set the feign logger level](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#logging), according to the [feign logger class](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/Logger.java#L128), you have 4 possible values, so probably you want to use `Logger.Level.FULL.`

Hope this help you.